# codenameone : Custom calendar button background

Tags: codenameone

I need to create a calendar with different background colors depending on the content of the daybuttons, how can i make  the colors fix : unchanged when selecting another date using codenameone.

i tried a simple modification but when selecting a button the colors turn back to white as configured in the theme (i use UI builder)

```
@Override
    protected void updateButtonDayDate(Button dayButton, int year, int   currentMonth, int day) {
        //dayButton.setUIID("Container");
        dayButton.getAllStyles().setPaddingTop(3);
        dayButton.getAllStyles().setPaddingBottom(3);
        dayButton.getAllStyles().setBgColor(ColorUtil.BLUE);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `setChangesSelectedDateEnabled(false)` also make sure that the button doesn't have a border and that it's opaque by doing this:

```
Style s = dayButton.getAllStyles();
s.setPaddingTop(3);
s.setPaddingBottom(3);
s.setBgColor(ColorUtil.BLUE);
s.setBgTransparency(255);
s.setBorder(null);
```

Comment: It's better,  but i have set an action listener on the calendar in order to list the appointments list in the selected date. so using setChangesSelectedDateEnabled(false) won't help do this.

Comment: How can i reset the calendar to its initiale state ? i guess i could reinitialize it on every selection.

Comment: Never mind, i guess i can develop a mechanism to reset the last unselected button, on every new selection. Thanks.